# Using LMR400 and RG8x in the same feedline

Tags: coaxial-cable, feed-line

I am putting a run together from my shack to a new 2 meter antenna I've built.  I'm blessed to have many trees on my property and I'll be placing the new antenna about 90 ft from the ground by hanging it off a pine.

The plan is to use LMR400 for the run from the shack to antenna which is about 200' total.  To make antenna installation easier and friendlier for maintenance I was planning on using RG8x on the actual antenna installation and tie in the LMR400 about 15 feet away from the antenna to the RG8x at the top of the tree.

Currently I'm running the antenna on about 100' of RG8x but its not really positioned high enough (its about 25' off the ground).

I assume there will be some negligible loss when transitioning from LMR400 to RG8x but I hadn't heard of people doing this.  Perhaps its common practice.

I'm running the cable tomorrow and wanted to see if there was some insight to avoid climbing the pine more than a few times :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to mix two different types of coax like this, providing that they have the same impedance (in this case 50Ω). Any loss in good splices should be negligible.